Scraping a website that contains _dopostback method written
I am trying to scrape with jsoup in java, obtain information from the "stdregistro" table and save it in a table in my database at this URL:
pad.minem.gob.pe/REINFO_WEB/Index.aspx
but I only get information from the first page and not from the following pages of the table
I will show you an example of my code so far, where I get the information but only from the first page
public class apiscraping {

    private static final String URL = "https://pad.minem.gob.pe/REINFO_WEB/Index.aspx";
    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxx:1433;databaseName=xxxxx;user=xxxx;password=xxxxx";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            scrapeAndStore();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private static void scrapeAndStore() throws Exception {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        int pageNumber = 1;
        boolean hasNextPage = true;

        while (hasNextPage) {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
            Elements rows = doc.select("#stdregistro tr");

            for (Element row : rows) {
                Elements columns = row.select("td");
                if (columns.size() > 0) {
                    String ruc = columns.get(2).text();
                    String mineroFormal = columns.get(3).text();
                    String codigoUnico = columns.get(4).text();
                    String nombre = columns.get(5).text();
                    String departamento = columns.get(6).text();
                    String provincia = columns.get(7).text();
                    String distrito = columns.get(8).text();
                    String estado = columns.get(9).text();

                    saveToDatabase(ruc, mineroFormal, codigoUnico, nombre, departamento, provincia, distrito, estado);
                }
            }

            hasNextPage = navigateToNextPage(httpClient, doc);
            System.out.println("Processed page: " + pageNumber);
            pageNumber++;
        }

        httpClient.close();
    }

    private static boolean navigateToNextPage(CloseableHttpClient httpClient, Document doc) throws IOException {
        Element nextButton = doc.select("#ImgBtnSiguiente").first();
        if (nextButton == null || nextButton.hasAttr("disabled")) {
            return false;
        }

        String viewState = doc.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATE]").val();
        String eventValidation = doc.select("input[name=__EVENTVALIDATION]").val();
        String viewStateGenerator = doc.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR]").val();
        String txtpagina = doc.select("input[name=txtpagina]").val();
        int nextPage = Integer.parseInt(txtpagina) + 1;

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
        List<BasicNameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__VIEWSTATE", viewState));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidation));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", viewStateGenerator));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtpagina", String.valueOf(nextPage)));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ImgBtnSiguiente.x", "1"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ImgBtnSiguiente.y", "1"));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);

        Document nextDoc = Jsoup.parse(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8", URL);
        response.close();

        return nextDoc != null;
    }

    private static void saveToDatabase(String ruc, String mineroFormal, String codigoUnico, String nombre, String departamento, String provincia, String distrito, String estado) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO OPE_REINFO (OPE_RUC, OPE_MINEROFORMAL, OPE_CODIGOUNICO, OPE_NOMBRE, OPE_DEPARTAMENTO, OPE_PROVINCIA, OPE_DISTRITO, OPE_ESTADO) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
             PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {

            pstmt.setString(1, ruc);
            pstmt.setString(2, mineroFormal);
            pstmt.setString(3, codigoUnico);
            pstmt.setString(4, nombre);
            pstmt.setString(5, departamento);
            pstmt.setString(6, provincia);
            pstmt.setString(7, distrito);
            pstmt.setString(8, estado);

            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Inserted record: RUC = " + ruc + ", Minero = " + mineroFormal + ", Código Único = " + codigoUnico);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error inserting record: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

any suggestion, help is welcome, thanks
I think the problem lies in how information is obtained from said table. Since I am new to scraping, I am still trying, but any advice is welcome.
